# How to send a text message to a microsoft teams online meeting?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am interested in doing the following with a csharp based teams bot:

1. Create an online meeting.
2. Invite several people into it.
3. Send a text message to this online meeting.

I am able to accomplish steps 1 and 2 with the graph communications api.
My bot can do many other tasks like (1) receive and reply to personal messages, (2) send proactive messages, (3) handle compose messaging extension invocations, (4) add the bot and send to groupchats, etc.

However, I have tried several approaches to step 3, and none have worked.  I am getting this 403 Forbidden error when I try to send the message to the conversation:

```
{"error":{"code":"BotNotInConversationRoster","message":"The bot is not part of the conversation roster."}}
```

I have also reviewed this github thread:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/1772

I have tried adding the bot to the online meeting in a manner similar to adding the bot to a group chat, but the online meeting conversation does not appear in the search screen (when (1) going to the bot's info page from the 'Apps' menu, then (2) clicking 'Add to a chat', then (3) trying to find the conversation in the 'Select a chat to start using MyBot' search window that appears)

[Add Bot to Chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlQft.png)

The request to send the message looks something like this:

```
POST https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/v3/conversations/19:meeting_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@thread.v2/activities/f:2XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
  "type": "message",
  "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
  "channelId": "msteams",
  "from": {
    "id": "28:5fXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "HelpDesk Bot"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "id": "19:meeting_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@thread.v2",
    "tenantId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "recipient": {
    "id": "29:12XXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "name": "SupportTest",
    "aadObjectId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  },
  "text": "Welcome to the support session.",
  "inputHint": "acceptingInput",
  "attachments": [],
  "entities": [],
  "replyToId": "f:2XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: added some more screen shots of menus available in the meeting chat room:
[Online meeting menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWG9R.png)
[Compose menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlaol.png)

-Tom

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try adding the bot from "Manage Apps" section under your meeting chat menu(the three dots next to the meeting chat title)?

[image]

You can then add the bot by choosing "upload a custom app" option from the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure which 3 dots button you are referring.  The main one in the online meeting screen doesn't show any "apps" option.  I have configured a compose messaging extension for this bot, when I click on the 3 dots next to the message compose box, it shows the indicated screen.  I can click my bot here, but it opens the messaging extension I have configured.  I do see the invocation callback come into my bot, but the bot still gets a Forbidden error when it tries to send a message to the conversation.  I don't see any other 3 dots button.

Comment: Ahh, I found it in the 'chat' list, but it is for an older online meeting.  I am not able to see this listing for the newly created online meeting that my bot just created.  It does work when I click through this 3 dot button and add my bot.  After that point, my bot is able to send text messages into the online meeting chat.  Is there an easier way to accomplish this, exclusively from the bot side, requiring no additional steps from the user?

Comment: Currently this is the only way to add Bots to meeting chats. We are working on making this experience better. Thanks!